# Why does a "function name" evaluate to true in C and how to get warned on it

Tags: c, gcc-warning

I recently stumbled across the following behaviour of gcc 3.2.2 writing a c program:

In an if statement I forgot the braces of a function and wrote:

`if(myFunc)...` instead of `if(myFunc())...`

This did not generate an error neither a warning although I have pretty much every warning turned on.

It simply evaluated to `true`.
Why is this writing legal code in the first place ? 
Because the function  exists/has an address ?
Does anyone know how one could avoid such mistakes or if there is a warning option I overlooked ? Is this issue better solved in later gcc versions ?

Here the exact compiler call for completeness:

```
 msp430-gcc -g -Os -mmcu=msp430x1611 -Wall -W -Wfloat-equal -Wundef -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wbad-function-cast -Wcast-qual -Wwrite-strings -Wsign-compare -Waggregate-return -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations 
-Wredundant-decls -Wnested-externs -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Werror
```

(Since I'm forced to use gcc 3.2.3 there is no -Wextra)

Comment: As long as `myFunc` is defined this is guaranteed true and the branch always taken, so you would expect there to some dead code if there is an `else` branch. That might trigger a warning... Also my `man gcc` says *" -Wextra (This option used to be called -W.  The older name still supported, but the newer name is more descriptive.)"*

Comment: Is `myFunc` a function or a function pointer?

Comment: @Adam: myFunc() is an ordinary function

Comment: @dmckee: -W disables warings in gcc 3.2.3 http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2.3/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options

Comment: @Martin: Ah, formatting lost in translation; that's `-W.`. Presumably the full-stop is part of the flag...

Comment: @Martin, @dmckee, `-W` does not disable warnings.  As dmckee said, it's equivalent to the newer `-Wextra`; the 3.2.3 docs say, "Print extra warning messages for these events".  Note that you're using it above.  `-w` (lowercase) means "Inhibit all warning messages".  Both could have been named better.  There is no `-W.`.

Comment: @dmckee: LOL my appologies. Having a quick browse through the link I posted I found -w (small caps) and not -W my mistake ;-) -W without point does indeed sth. similar to -Wextra

Comment: @Matthew you are right, I'm already using it (it's been some time I decided the warning options), but still no joy for the described problem

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`if (myFunc)` is equivalent to `if (&myFunc)`, so you're testing the address of a function, which of course will always be non-zero, i.e. true.

With gcc 4.2.1 and `-Wall` I get the following warning:

`myfunc.c:11: warning: the address of ‘myFunc’ will always evaluate as ‘true’`

Comment: I feared sth. like that. Any Idea how to get warned with older gcc versions (3.2.2) ?

Comment: @Martin: all I can suggest is using a newer version of gcc

Comment: Does ANSI C declare that it will always be non-zero? (Unlikely /= always.)

Comment: @Conrad: hard to say, but if you change the test to `if (myFunc != NULL)` then the gcc warning changes to `myfunc.c:11: warning: the address of ‘myFunc’ will never be NULL`, which tends to suggest that function addresses can never be zero (not authoritative, I know).

Comment: @Conrad: yes, every pointer that is valid is guaranteed to evaluate non equal against a null pointer.

Comment: Thanks! [extra characters for stackoverflow to accept the comment]

Answer (score 3):

`myFunc` is simply the memory address of the function, and is non-zero.

Your if-statement is pretty much the same as writing:

```
if (0x08451234) { ... }
```

And as a non-zero value, it is `true`.

No warning seems appropriate, as it is valid and even somewhat common to test function-pointers to see if they are NULL or not.

Comment: It's common to test function *pointers*.  It is not common to test *functions*, which always have a non-zero address.

Comment: I'm not sure there is much of a difference in compiled code between a function-pointer and a function.  They're both just addresses that can be jmp'd to.

Comment: abelenky: There is. One is a memory location which contains the address of the function (and can be reassigned), while the other is simply the literal address.

Comment: This is like the array/pointer distinction: function names *decay* to function pointers in places where the later is appropriate, but it is clearer to maintain a semantic distinction.

Comment: I think the big differentiator here is that a function name is *never* null. The compiler can clearly and easily tell that a function will never be zero, but a function pointer may be set to NULL somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

`myFunc`, since its the name of a function will always evaluate to `true` because its a pointer.  More specifically it *has* to be a non-null pointer because you will be needing to dereference it.  A `null` pointer would evaluate to `false`.

In short, there does not seem to be a way for the compiler to tell you that you've made a mistake.

What you need to do is to have some unit tests that separately invoke the `true` and `false` responses so that you can tell that you've actually called the function.

Answer (score 0):

Pointers to functions are sometimes useful - as callbacks eg in sort routines or data capture. Or for doing optimized calculated-goto type routines, since C doesn't have templates.

But 99% of the time it's an error, newer compilers will warn you

Answer (score 0):

This is to support an old linker hack; many compilers/linkers (including gcc and GNU binutils) allow you to define a weak symbol for a function which evaluates to 0 unless another object file/shared library that got linked overrides the value of the symbol. glibc makes use of this trick for some version-compatibility hacks.

Comment: Is that really why there's no warning?