# Why pointer to function is equal to 1?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, implicit-conversion

Check following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int& foo() {
    static int i = 0;
    return i;
}

int main() {
    cout << &foo() << endl;
    cout << &foo << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

As you see, the first `cout` prints address of return value of `foo()` which will be static variable `i` inside `foo()`. For 2nd `cout` I was expecting that `&foo` returns address of `foo()` function, as stated [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_address-of_operator):

> 2) If the operand is a qualified name of a non-static member, e.g.
>   &C::member, the result is a prvalue pointer to member function or
>   pointer to data member of type T in class C. Note that neither &member
>   nor C::member nor even &(C::member) may be used to initialize a
>   pointer to member.

But to my surprise, this is my output:

```
0x5650dc8dc174
1
```

First one is ok, but 2nd one is `1`? How this happened? To make sure that I have not messed up anything, I wrote this code in `C`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo() {
}

int main(void) {
    printf("%p", &foo);
    return 0;
}
```

with following output:

```
0x55732bd426f0
```

which works as expected. Have I missed up something in `C++` code? or maybe this is because of inlining `foo` function (even though it should not be like this)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328215/why-does-a-function-name-evaluate-to-true-in-c-and-how-to-get-warned-on-it - it's using it as a bool.

Comment: Note that “foo” is *not* “a qualified name of a non-static member” – `foo` isn’t even a member of anything – so the text you quoted does not apply.

Comment: Adding another ref: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt - see notes section

Comment: @Caramiriel in that question there is no conversion to `bool`. Address of a function is always non-zero so is evaluated (not converted) to true. In this question there is a conversion to `bool` because no overloads of `operator<<` best match to function pointer arguments other than `bool`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`std::basic_ostream::operator<<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) has two overloads taking `bool` and `const void*`. (There're other overloads taking function pointer with different signature which doesn't match with `foo`.)

> ```
> basic_ostream& operator<<( bool value );        (6)   
> basic_ostream& operator<<( const void* value ); (7)
> ```

For both `int*` and function pointer passed to `std::basic_ostream::operator<<`, implicit conversions are required here.

When passing `int*`, the (7) overload is selected because the implicit conversion [converting from `int*` to `const void*`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Pointer_conversions) is perferred than the one converting to `bool` in [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution),

> If two conversion sequences are indistinguishable because they have
> the same rank, the following additional rules apply:
>
> 1. Conversion that involves pointer to bool, pointer-to-member to
>    bool, or std::nullptr_t to bool conversion is worse than the one that
>    doesn't

and

> A prvalue pointer to any (optionally cv-qualified) object type T can be converted to a prvalue pointer to (identically cv-qualified) void. The resulting pointer represents the same location in memory as the original pointer value.

When passing function pointer, the (6) overload is selected; function pointer can be [converted to `bool` implicitly](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Boolean_conversions), but not to `const void*`.

> A prvalue of integral, floating-point, unscoped enumeration, pointer,
> and pointer-to-member types can be converted to a prvalue of type
> bool.
>
> The value zero (for integral, floating-point, and unscoped
> enumeration) and the null pointer and the null pointer-to-member
> values become false. All other values become true.

Comment: why function pointers can not implicitly converted to `const void*`?

Comment: yea it is strange for me too. why function pointer is not implicitly cast to `const void*`? Is there any standard restriction for this? because converting to `const void*` is much more logical than `bool`....

Comment: @user463035818 Afshin There's just no such implicit convesion; only pointer to object type could conver to `void*` implicitly. See [Pointer conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Pointer_conversions).

Comment: @songyuanyao hmm: *A prvalue pointer to any (optionally cv-qualified) object type T can be converted to a prvalue pointer to (identically cv-qualified) void.* shouldn't this apply to function pointers too?

Comment: @Afshin No, *object type* is not *function type*.

Comment: Because implicit conversion for function pointer to `void *` is possible in `C`, I was expected to be possible in `C++` too. My mistake, but I didn't think this has changed.

Comment: @Afshin There're many subtle differences between C++ and C; it's better to just think they're different language.

Comment: @Afshin C has no implicit conversion from pointers to functions to void*. If you're using gcc, never forget `-pedantic-errors`

Comment: @Cubbi but standard states that: *A pointer to void can be implicitly converted to and from any pointer to object type*

Comment: @Afshin sure, but that is not relevant. This discussion is about function pointers.

Comment: @Cubbi oh,my mistake. thanks for info.

Comment: "*note there's no overload taking function pointer*" - actually, there is (3 overloads, in fact). It is just that such function pointers must have a specific signature in order to be passed to `operator<<`, and the functions in question simply do not match those signatures.

Answer (score 1):

There is no overload for `operator<<` that matches the function pointer. So best match is `basic_ostream& operator<<(bool value)`.

There is another overload of `operator<<` as `basic_ostream& operator<<(const void * value)`. But function pointers could not implicitly cast to `const void*`.

If you would like to print the address of a function you could cast it to `void *` by using `reinterpret_cast` or C style casts.

Answer (score 1):

What you see is that the

```
std::ostream& operator<<( bool );
```

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt):

> There are no overload for pointers to non-static member, pointers to
>   volatile, or **function pointers** (other than the ones with
>   signatures accepted by the (10-12) overloads). Attempting to output
>   such objects invokes implicit conversion to bool, and, for any
>   non-null pointer value, the value 1 is printed (unless boolalpha was
>   set, in which case true is printed).

To see the pointer value you can cast to `void*`:

```
std::cout << (void*)foo;
```